# Oracle: How to query distinct records from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, duplicates, left-join

I want to query multiple tables but only return unique records.

**My current query:**

```
select 
    a.*, 
    b.*, 
    c.*
from c_inv a 
    inner join p_master b 
        on a.c_code = b.c_code 
            and a.p_code = b.p_code
    left join c_proj c 
        on b.c_code = c.c_code 
            and b.p_code = c.p_code
where a.c_code = 'AA'
    and a.d_type = 'IN' 
    and a.s_type = substr('OI',0,2)
    and a.g_flag = 'N'     
    and a.startdate <= trunc(sysdate)     
    and nvl(a.enddate, trunc(sysdate)) >= trunc(sysdate)
order by a.p_code
```

**Data Sample**

```
p_master
c_code  p_code
AA      Test01          
AA      Test02
AA      Test03

c_proj
c_code  p_code      proj    startdate   enddate
AA      Test99      clound  01/10/2016  31/10/2016
AA      Test99      clound  01/09/2016  30/09/2016
AA      Test99      clound  01/08/2016  31/08/2016
```

**my current results:**

```
c_code  p_code
AA      Test01          
AA      Test02
AA      Test03
AA      Test99
AA      Test99
AA      Test99
```

**Target results:**

```
c_code  p_code      proj
AA      Test01      null    
AA      Test02      null
AA      Test03      null
AA      Test99      clound
```

Comment: It seems that you're missing `c_inv` data

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this output is USEFUL, but to get it, you need `UNION`, not a join. (Note - `UNION` also does a `DISTINCT` operation so you don't need to add it separately.)

```
select p_code, c_code, null as proj from p_master
union
select p_code, c_code,         proj from c_proj
```

The results may come in the order you showed, or in any other order; use explicit `ORDER BY ....` if you need a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

if there is one-to-one mapping between c_code+p_code against project then following query will work:

```
select  a.c_code,a.p_code,max(proj)
from    c_inv a 
inner join p_master b 
    on  a.c_code = b.c_code 
    and a.p_code = b.p_code
left join c_proj c 
    on  b.c_code = c.c_code 
    and b.p_code = c.p_code
where   a.c_code = 'AA'
    and a.d_type = 'IN' 
    and a.s_type = substr('OI',0,2)
    and a.g_flag = 'N'     
    and a.startdate <= trunc(sysdate)     
    and nvl(a.enddate, trunc(sysdate)) >= trunc(sysdate)
group   by a.c_code,a.p_code    
order   by a.p_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to reduce the number of rows.  That suggests one of two approaches:  either aggregation or use of a window function such as `row_number()`.  The aggregation approach would look like:

```
select i.c_code, i.p_code, max(p.proj) as proj
from c_inv i inner join
     p_master m
     on i.c_code = m.c_code and i.p_code = m.p_code left join
     c_proj p
     on m.c_code = p.c_code and m.p_code = p.p_code
where i.c_code = 'AA' and
      i.d_type = 'IN' and
      i.s_type = substr('OI', 1, 2) and
      i.g_flag = 'N' and
      i.startdate <= trunc(sysdate) and    
      nvl(i.enddate, trunc(sysdate)) >= trunc(sysdate)
group by i.c_code, i.p_code;
```

I changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names.  This makes it easier to follow the query.

Also, in SQL, the positions in strings start at "1" and not "0", so I changed the `substr()` call.

Comment: `distinct` also reduces the number of rows (and seems to match the OP's output). And `distinct` is subsumed by set-theoretical operations (except `union all` - which is NOT a set-theoretical operation anyway).